# How to add the Values in String Array which one enter through User?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am tring to add all the values in String Array but it don't work:

```
public class Info extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "Info";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
    Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras(); 
    String choice = b.getString("choice"); 
    String fname = b.getString("fname");
    String lname = b.getString("lname");
    String add = b.getString("add");
    String coun = b.getString("coun");
    String pro = b.getString("pro");
    String pcode = b.getString("pcode");

   Log.i(TAG,"selection: " + choice); 
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showmeText); 
   textView.append(": " + choice); 
   TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fname); 
   textView1.append(" " + fname); 
   TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lname); 
   textView2.append(" " + lname); 
   TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address1); 
   textView3.append(" " + add); 
   TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pro); 
   textView4.append(" " + pro); 
   TextView textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country1); 
   textView5.append(" " + coun); 
   TextView textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pcode); 
   textView6.append(" " + pcode); 

}
```

I tried these all values in ListView but these not working because i was adding all the Textview in ListView.Can you please help me How to add these list in String array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Crete a ListView in your UI Deisgn layout xml. 


<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:id="@+id/choice_list" 
            android:focusable="false"
                   android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">







Step1 : Create a String Array ex: String[] myStringArray.

Step 2: Push all the string values into Array.
Step 3 : in your activity get the reference for listview (choice_list)

Ex:


ListView choiceListView = (ListView)findviewById(R.layout.choice_list)

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myStringArray);
```

choiceListView .setAdapter(adapter);

```
That is all to see the out put as list view in normal activity. You don't need ListActivity , but can use this in normal activity too. The above is the solution for any activity which has a listview as a component in it. 

If you like this please vote for me.
```

Comment: How to push all the values in String Array,I have all the values in different- different variables.Please help me.I am stuck in this problem...

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
public class ArrayAdapterDemo extends ListActivity {
   TextView selection;

   "silly", "list" };
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       item.add(choice);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
      this,
      android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
      items));
selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection); 
   }
```

Comment: I have 6-7 string how to add all these ones...Can you please tell what is item..Is it string variable or string array and whats is items where we declare this..?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] myStringArray = new String[7];
myStringArray[0] = choice;
myStringArray[1] = fname;
......
myStringArray[7] = pcode ;

Or you want to display all the text in a single textview. Your question is not clear.

I hope if its about pushing the values into the array then the above holds good.
```

Comment: I tried same thing but when i run this application on Emulator it show me error message i mean it doesn't run.

Comment: pls put the error here. I guess i might me because of either value missing or class cast exception

Answer (score 0):

pls paste the error here. I guess i might me because of either value missing or class cast exception.

Comment: It show me Page load error it show me **The application Animation (process com.example.animation) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.**

Comment: I am passing all the values through menu-item is it ok...?